# tf view_frames reinstall

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, tf commands have disappeared, is there a way to reinstall them (view_frames I need). Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71920/tf-view_frames-reinstall/) by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-08-12**:
have you tried: sudo apt-get install ros--geometry ?

**Comment by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) on 2013-08-26**:
yes I did.

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-08-26**:
does it work ?
does 'rospack find tf' return the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was typing view_frames instead of rosrun tf view_frames as it worked before with just view_frames, thanks for the help.

---

Originally posted by [boog](https://answers.ros.org/users/5329/boog/) with karma: 18 on 2013-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0